# React onClick on div element

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have created one Object in a file config.js

```
export const handleClick =() => {
   return "hi"
}

export const abc = {
  'a': 'rollNo',
  'b': 'age',
  'c': `<div onClick='${handleClick}'>Click 
       Me</div>`
}
```

I am iterating over the object in table and values are printed in table.

When I click on div,nothing happens.onClick event is not tiggered in react.

Can anyone please tell whats the issue

Comment: remove `''` around ${handleClick} and do console.log inside handleClick.

Comment: @MayankShukla I tired removing ''.But then I get error Reference Error : Unexpected end of Input {

Comment: try this: `<div onClick={${handleClick}}>`

Comment: When I did this,I am getting error uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected end of Input

Answer (score 0):

React component cannot be stored in strings, instead, make an arrow function that returns a JSX element :

```
export const handleClick =() => {
   return "hi"
}

export const abc = {
  'a': 'rollNo',
  'b': 'age',
  'c': () => <div onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</div>
}
```

You will then have to call it when you need to render anything, the same goes for your other strings if they are supposed to behave in the same way :

```
export const handleClick =() => {
   return "hi"
}

export const abc = {
  'a': () => 'rollNo',
  'b': () => 'age',
  'c': () => <div onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</div>
}
```

Working example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const handleClick = () => { console.log('hi !') }

        const abc = {
            'a': () => 'rollNo',
            'b': () => 'age',
            'c': () => < div onClick={handleClick}> Click Me </div>
        }

        return (
            <div> {abc.c()} </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Why is your `onClick` handler a string literal?

Comment: No idea, didn't notice this error at first in the OP's post

Comment: By doing this      export const abc = {
  'a': 'rollNo',
  'b': 'age',
  'c': () => <div onClick='${handleClick}'>Click Me</div>
} getting error component is missing in 'react/display-name

Comment: @Treycos I am doing like this import * as config from 'one.js';

Comment: Then just import and use it instead of putting it in a local variable like I did. `abc` and `handleclick` can be outside of the class if needed

Comment: @Treycoss I am doing like this import * as config from 'one.js';  then creating component .. code snippet is return Object.keys(config).map((key,index)                           return ( <tr key ={index}> <td dangerously stunner HTML = {{ _html: config.abc[key]> <td/> </tr>)

Comment: Please edit your original question with the additionnal information and be clearer about what you want. Code is hard to read and understand in a comment

Comment: @Treycos I would like to iterate over object and display object values in table

Comment: Please read my previous comment or nobody will be able to help you

Comment: And what you're asking now isn't related at all to your question. You should accept the answer currently working for your question and then ask another one on the forum

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
export const abc = {
  'a': 'rollNo',
  'b': 'age',
  'c': `<div onClick={${handleClick}}>Click 
   Me</div>`
}
```

Comment: When I did this,I am getting error uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected end of Input

Comment: Can you show that how are you using this in code? It will be much more helpful to answer.

Comment: I am doing something like this import * as config from 'one.js';  then creating component .. code snippet is return Object.keys(config).map((key,index)                           return ( <tr key ={index}> <td dangerously stunner HTML = {{ _html: config.abc[key]> <td/> </tr>)

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.